# Read Rdata file in python

Tags: python, r

I am having trouble reading a `.Rdata` file (generated by the program [nonpareil](https://github.com/lmrodriguezr/nonpareil)) into python (example data [here](https://github.com/ewels/MultiQC/files/11894162/sample_data.zip)).

I tried `pyreadr`, but got the error:

```
LibrdataError: The file contains an unrecognized object
```

The other option was to export the `R` object as a `JSON` (with `jsonlite`) and read it in python. I went a bit further, but commas are taken literally (and escaped) and all values are assumed as strings.

```
library("jsonlite")
# Get variable names
n <- names(attributes(curves$np.curves[[1]]))[1:29]
# Extract values
d <- sapply(curves$np.curves, function(x) lapply(n, function(v) toJSON(attr(x,v), auto_unbox=TRUE)))
names(d) <- n
# Prettify
a <- lapply(apply(d, 2, toJSON, auto_unbox=TRUE), prettify)
```

Any way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [**`pyreadr`**](https://github.com/ofajardo/pyreadr), the Python package is designed to read in R data frames or other tabular structured objects not *any* R object, notably including `list`:

> It can read mainly R data frames and tibbles. Also supports vectors, matrices, arrays and tables. R lists and R S4 objects (such as those from Bioconductor) are not supported.

Do note: an `.RData` file stores an entire R workspace held in global or other environment to disk, so can contain *many* objects of *any* type. Conversely, an `.Rds` file stores only a single object.

Recall too, R is a general-purpose <s>language</s> environment similar to Python and can have *many* extendable data structures and class objects beyond data frames (which itself is a `class` object in the R `base` package akin to Python's standard library).

Upon reading the samples in linked zip file, these are special `class` objects requiring the `Nonpareil` package.

```r
load("sample.RData")
ls()
# [1] "curves"

str(curves)
# Loading required package: Nonpareil
# Error in .requirePackage(package) : 
#   unable to find required package ‘Nonpareil’
# In addition: Warning message:
# In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
#   there is no package called ‘Nonpareil’

class(curves)
# [1] "Nonpareil.Set"
attr(,"package")
# [1] "Nonpareil"
```

Hence, `pyreadr` raised the `unrecognized object` error. To resolve, consider using this R package to extract out or convert the object(s) into vanilla data frames or other tabular structures. Then save as `RData` or `Rds` files to be read in `pyreadr`. Alternatively, save data frames into textual formats (.csv, .tab, .json) to be read in Python without extended packages.